# ROR + Trying to access RESTful URL from VB.Net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vb.net, web-services

In my rails application, I am using rails web-service to authenticate the User.
Here URL :

> https://www.test.com/AuthenticateUser?username=tuser@mailinator.com&password=123456

Here I am passing username and password to AuthenticateUser Method to validate the user. It is working fine with my rails app. But when I tried to access this from .Net Code but I am getting `error 406`.

> ' Call json web service

```
  String uri = "https://www.test.com/AuthenticateUser?username=tuser@mailinator.com&password=123456";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Method = "GET";
req.Accept = "application/json";
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
```

I guess, when I am accessing it from .net code, it is supposed to be an cross domain call. Does it have any effect on the result?

I am getting error : The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.
Please suggest some thing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[406](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) means that your client specified that it would not accept the formats that the web service is willing to give.

Assuming that the response is `application/json`, you can [change the `Accept` header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
req.Accept = "application/json"
```

If it doesn't work, that means that the web service doesn't actually give responses in `application/json`, and you should take another look at what it actually does serve.

If you don't believe the server's 406, then you should start looking at the web service code and see why it's returning a 406 even though it can produce a `application/json` response, and the request has `application/json` included in its `Accept` header.

Comment: WE have already added above header. To add to the question, It is a cross domain request. Does this have any effect on this?

Comment: No.  Check your header again.  406 can only mean that.

Comment: How do i check whether it is returning me application/json response or not?